# Find an exact word in a string

Tags: c#, string, linq-to-entities

How do i find out if a string is containing the exact word i am looking for?

example: "this is my text"; word looking for: "text"; found: yes.

example: "these are my texts"; word looking for: "text"; found: no.

- it's inside a linq to entities query, so regex won't work?

**Edit:**

This is more or less what i'm doing now and i want to replace it by a function that returns only when it's the exact match.

```
    using (Model.Manager ctx = new Model.Manager())
    {
        var result = from p in ctx.Companies where p.Name.Contains(workLookingFor) select p;        
    }
```

**Solution so far:**

I could use .Contains() on my DB and use RegEx on the results pulled from the DB. Since the exact matches are always inside the broader results from .Contains() (which i still need anyways) this could be a good solution

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the Linq2Entities, such as a code example?

Comment: You can't use a `.Select()` with Regex match, and `\btext\b` patttern?

Comment: @Brad Christie, see my comment to Tim Roger's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way. You have three options

- run your query, then do the pattern matching on the client
- use SQL Fulltext Search engine
- add a [CLR function to the database that lets you do regex matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

Comment: Yuk. But you gave me an idea. I could use .Contains() on my DB and use RegEx on the results pulled from the DB. Since the exact matches are always inside the broader results from .Contains() (which i still need anyways) this could be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. It's not perfect but might help.

```
 public static  bool matchWholeWord(string test, string search)
        {
            var index = test.IndexOf(search);
            if (index == -1)
                return false;

            var after = index + search.Length;
            if (after == test.Length)
                return true;

            return !char.IsLetterOrDigit(test[after]);
        }
```

in your code:

```
using (Model.Manager ctx = new Model.Manager())
    {
        var result = from p in ctx.Companies 
        where matchWholeWord(p.Name, workLookingFor) 
        select p;        
    }
```

Comment: How would that perform on 200.000 records with 3 text fields and multiple words to search?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use something similar to this to implement a search algorithm using LINQ recently. I found the MSDN article on combining [LINQ and Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882639.aspx) to be useful, along with a regular expression that used the space marker to identify whitespace. By constructing the regex with my search parameters and combining that into my LINQ expression, I ended up with what I needed.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection Matches(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: It's unfortunate that LINQ to Entities has this behavior. Good luck.